# Split Alpha And Numeric Using SQL Separate in Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, substring

I have records that that in some times came with one text and one number and sometimes two, three or four and they are separated with two point ':'. i want to split the numeric and the text in multiple column.

Here is a record example:
**March : 1 April : 2 May : 10 June : 1**

desired result :

| Str_1 | item_1 | Str_2 | item_2 | Str_3 | item_3 | Str_4 | item_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| March | 1 | April | 2 | May | 10 | June | 1 |

I'm using SQL SERVER 2012

i made this script but it doesn't work with all the cases

```
select substring(@str,1,charindex(':',@str)-1) as str_Type,

case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then substring(@str,charindex(':',@str)+1,len(@str)) 
  else substring(ltrim(
                            SUBSTRING(
                                                  substring(replace
                                                                (@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                                                                LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))) 
                                                  ,1
                                                  ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace
                                                                                            (@str,'-',''),
                                                                                            CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                                                                                            LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))-1))
                                   ,1
                                   ,charindex(' ',ltrim(SUBSTRING(
                                                                                                           substring(replace(
                                                                                                                                @str,'-',''),
                                                                                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                                                                                                                                LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))) 
                                                                                                           ,1
                                                                                                          ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace
                                                                                                                                                     (@str,'-',''),
                                                                                                                                                     CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                                                                                                                                                     LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))-1)))-1)
  end as str_Unit,

     case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null 
  else substring(ltrim(SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace(@str,'-',''),CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))) 
                            ,1
                            ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))-1))
              ,charindex(' ',ltrim(SUBSTRING(substring(replace(@str,'-',''),CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))) ,1,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))-1)))+1
              ,len(ltrim(SUBSTRING(substring(replace(@str,'-',''),CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))) ,1,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))-1)))) 
  end as str_type_2 ,

  LEFT(case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))))
   End, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))))
   End )) as str_Unit_2,



    case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,len(ltrim(SUBSTRING(substring(replace(@str,'-',''),CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))) ,1,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))-1))))))
   End as str_type_3,

              
        reverse(LEFT(reverse(LEFT(case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))) end, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))) end ))), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', reverse(LEFT(case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))) end, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))) end ))) ))) str_Unit_3,


              replace(LTRIM(RIGHT( case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))) end, LEN( case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))) end) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%',  case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))) end ))),reverse(LEFT(reverse(LTRIM(RIGHT( case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))) end, LEN( case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))) end) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%',  case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))) end )))), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', reverse(LTRIM(RIGHT( case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))) end, LEN( case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))) end) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%',  case when  len(@str)-len(replace(@str,':',''))=1 then null
  else SUBSTRING(
                            substring(replace
                            (@str,'-',''),
                            PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,
                            LEN(replace(@str,'-','')))
              ,CHARINDEX(':',substring(replace(@str,'-',''),
                                                                CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))+1,len(substring(replace(@str,'-','')
                                                                ,CHARINDEX(':',replace(@str,'-',''))+1
              ,LEN(replace(@str,'-',''))))) end )))) )+2)),'')  str_Type_4,


    substring( @str,DATALENGTH(@str)-CHARINDEX(REVERSE(':'),REVERSE(@str))+3,len(@str)) as str_Unit_4


Thanks!
```

Comment: With respect, that code you've dumped is unreadable and I guarantee completely unecessary for something that sounds so simple. Add proper sample data and desired results to your question - also please confirm which SQL Server version.

Comment: I'm using SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: I've edited the original question, now it seems a little bit clear, can you help simplifying that code @Stu

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what that huge mess of code is supposed to do, but you can use `OPENJSON` with a bit of string-replace to split your text:

```sql
DECLARE @str varchar(max) = 'Text1 : 1 Text2 : 2 Text3 : 10 Text4 : 1';

SELECT
  j.[key],
  LEFT(j.value, v.pipe - 1),
  SUBSTRING(j.value, v.pipe + 1, LEN(j.value))
FROM OPENJSON(
  '["' +
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      @str,
      ' : ',
      '|'
    ),
    ' ',
    '","'
  )
  + '"]'
) j
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CHARINDEX('|', j.value)
) ) v(pipe);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f11feea6500878651cc4786f8480b51c)

If you want it on one row you can aggregate it.

Comment: I'm using SQL SERVER 2012 it does not support this i think

Comment: No it doesn't, but 2012 is end-of-lifed in 2 months so I strongly suggest you think about upgrading

Comment: I've edited the original question, now it seems a little bit clear, can you help with that thank you

Comment: So what doesn't work about the code I gave you? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=72cb741bcdfd9431cccbea3e5c4fbce3

Comment: i need something supported in SSMS 2012, OPENJSON does not